# Firebase error? W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, build.gradle

So I'm fairly new to Java/Android. I tried to make a simple app with a Firebase connection where users can sign up and use that account to log into the app with.

I've managed to make them make an account, it gets stored correctly in the database, however when you try to log in using the account, it doesn't do anything and the following error occurs:

```
W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms
```

I've googeled around and tried many different solutions, but nothing works.

This is my build.gradle (Module: app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.gebruiker.androidchapclient"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    **implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'**
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.4'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Besides the Firebase error, the bold implementation is also giving me an error which I can't seem to solve.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please change this line of code:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.4'
```

with

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.1'
```

Each version of `FirebaseUI` has dependency on a fixed version of the Firebase version. For more informations, please see [Compatibility with Firebase / Google Play Services libraries](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android).

Comment: When I do this I get a few errors in my java class files. Some FirebaseRecyclerAdapter errors

Comment: @Ninja Try to use the latest versions. This versions are 1 year old.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using these dependencies,

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
```